# Text + Continuous inputs in neural network in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I need helping debugging a piece of code in PyTorch. I am trying to build a neural network to predict certain labels (0, 1, 2) given continuous and textual features.

I am getting several errors regarding shapes and batched input sizes and I feel like I haven't been making any progress debugging the code for the last 3 hours.

The feature set is something like this

`X = 20,0.025921925628760993,0.032208588957055216,1,16839,7721,"[6331, 8116]","[262, 1930, 2205, 2255, 4022, 4225, 4266, 4274, 4275, 5414, 7096, 7113, 7146, 7192, 7478, 8941, 9082, 9648, 10467, 10507, 10539, 11100, 11914, 12525, 13262, 13492, 13635, 14079, 14219, 14900, 15053, 17031, 17394]",  y = 1`

Where the stringified lists are indexed tokens that are output from this function

```py
def _encode_string(self, col: pd.Series):
    mapping = {cat: i for i, cat in enumerate(col.astype("category").cat.categories)}
    encoded_col = []
    for cat in col:
       encoded_col.append(mapping[cat])
    return encoded_col
```

This is the code for my Torch dataset:

```py
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, max_seq_length=8) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.X = self.data.drop(columns=["label"])
        self.y = self.data["label"]
        self.max_seq_length = max_seq_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        features = {
            'x1': torch.tensor(self.X.iloc[idx]['x1'], dtype=torch.float), # cont. feature
            'x2': torch.tensor(self.X.iloc[idx]['x2'], dtype=torch.float), # cont. feature
            'x3': torch.tensor(self.X.iloc[idx]['x3'], dtype=torch.long), # encoded cat feature
            'x4': torch.tensor(self.X.iloc[idx]['x4'], dtype=torch.long), # encoded cat feature
            'x5': torch.tensor(self.X.iloc[idx]['x5'], dtype=torch.long), # encoded cat feature
            'x6': torch.tensor(eval(self.X.iloc[idx]['x6']), dtype=torch.long), # list of indices
            'x7': torch.tensor(eval(self.X.iloc[idx]['x7']), dtype=torch.long) # list of indices
        }

        # # pad sequences for the lists
        features['x6'] = torch.nn.functional.pad(features['x6'], pad=(0, self.max_seq_length - len(features['x6'])))
        features['x7'] = torch.nn.functional.pad(features['x7'], pad=(0, self.max_seq_length - len(features['x7'])))

        return features, self.y.iloc[idx]
```

Now the dataset gets created correctly and my problem is with the model itself. I'd like to create a model that uses embedding layers to deal with the categorical values and concatenates the embeddings with the continuous input data.

My attempt was something like this, but I don't know how to properly manage the changing input sizes and the fully connected layers' input dimension.

```py
class MyModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_dicts, embedding_dim, num_classes):
        super().__init__()
        self.emb = nn.ModuleList(
            [
                nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
                for vocab_size in vocab_dicts.values()
            ]
        )
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(0, 0)  # Initialize with zeros 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, num_classes)

    def forward(self, sample):
        to_embed = [
            sample["x3"],
            sample["x4"],
            sample["x5"],
            sample["x6"],
            sample["x7"],
        ]

        continuous = [
            sample["x1"],
            sample["x2"],
        ]

        embedded = [emb(x) for emb, x in zip(self.emb, to_embed)]
        # flatten where possible
        embedded = [x.flatten() for x in embedded]
        continuous = [x.flatten() for x in continuous]

        x = torch.cat(embedded + continuous)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(x.shape[0], 128)
        
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x

if __name__ == "__main__":

    vocab_dicts = {
        "x3": 4,
        "x4": 20000,
        "x5": 20000,
        "x6": 20000,
        "x7": 20000,
    }
    features, target = (
        {
            "x1": torch.tensor(0.0259),
            "x2": torch.tensor(0.0322),
            "x3": torch.tensor(1),
            "x4": torch.tensor(16839),
            "x5": torch.tensor(7721),
            "x6": torch.tensor([6331, 8116, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
            "x7": torch.tensor([262, 1930, 2205, 2255, 4022, 4225, 4266, 4274]),
        },
        0.0,
    )
    model = MyModel(vocab_dicts, 32, 3)
    print(model)
    print(model(features))
```

I've been just playing around with this model but keep on hitting a brick wall. Can someone please guide me in the understanding of how to deal with batched input, and managing with changing sizes?

Thank you

Comment: You're making life a lot harder by doing data preprocessing inline with the model. Merge all your token inputs into a single vocabulary. Your input to the model should be a batch of continuous features and a batch of categorical features. Send the cat features to a single embedding. Send the continuous features to a small MLP to project them into the same size as the embeddings. Concat the continuous embedding to your categorical embeddings. Go from there

Comment: Hey Karl, thank you for your comment. I understand what you say - you are right and will attempt to do that now.